# mysql maria DBServer query

Tags: mysql

This query is giving an error in mariaDB server

```
insert into Information(First_name,Last_name,Father_name,Mother_name,Gender,DOB,Address,entry_made)
values('Yx','Vx','O','S','f','1994-09-13','P',(CURDATE()  )  AS 'DD' );
```

The error is

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''DD' )' at line 1

information table is created as shown below

```
create table information (First_name varchar(100) ,Last_name varchar(100) ,Father_name varchar(100) ,Mother_name varchar(100) ,Gender enum ('m','f'),DOB date  ,Address varchar(100) ,entry_made date not null ,primary key(First_name,Last_name ,Father_name,Mother_name,Gender,DOB,Address  ));
```

Comment: It says you have an error near `'DD'` … and looking at it, I see `,(CURDATE()) AS 'DD'` but have absolutely no idea what that code is attempting to do. 
You need to provide a *clear problem statement*

Comment: You also need to read the help by the question editor. It tells you how to format your question so it is readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need CURDATE() no need for the alias or the extra parentheses:

```
insert into Information
      (First_name,Last_name,Father_name,Mother_name,Gender,DOB         ,Address,entry_made)
values('Yx'      ,'Vx'     ,'O'        ,'S'        ,'f'   ,'1994-09-13','P'    ,CURDATE())
;

CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`entry_made` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`entry_made`)
VALUES
    ('2017-03-02 00:00:00'),
    (CURDATE()),
    (NOW())
;
```

**Query**:

```
select * from table1

|           entry_made |
|----------------------|
| 2017-03-02T00:00:00Z |
| 2017-10-08T00:00:00Z |
| 2017-10-08T07:07:06Z |
```